# How to sort a list of dictionary for datetime key which also contains empty string and get the large value first?

Tags: python-3.x

The list of dictionary -

```
data = [{'key1':'','key2':'111'},{'key1':12,'key2':'1'},{'key1':1,'key2':'1'}]
```

Sorted is -

```
sorted(data, key=lambda k: (k['key1'] is None, k['key1'] == "", k['key1']),reverse=True)
```

Response -

```
[{'key1': '', 'key2': '111'}, {'key1': 12, 'key2': '1'}, {'key1': 1, 'key2': '1'}]
```

How do we get the large value first and move the empty string last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda x : x['key1'] if x['key1'] else float('-inf'), reverse=True)
[{'key1': 12, 'key2': '1'}, {'key1': 1, 'key2': '1'}, {'key1': '', 'key2': '111'}]
>>> # OR
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda x : x['key1'] if isinstance(x['key1'], int) else float('-inf'), reverse=True)
[{'key1': 12, 'key2': '1'}, {'key1': 1, 'key2': '1'}, {'key1': '', 'key2': '111'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def order(v):
    if v['key1'] in {'',None}:
        return -1
    else:
        return v['key1']


sorted(data,key=order,reverse=True)

[{'key1': 12, 'key2': '1'}, {'key1': 1, 'key2': '1'}, {'key1': '', 'key2': '111'}]
```